# Is it possible to attach custom key/values automatically collected events by Google Analytics for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Like If I want to pass Device details to Firebase automated events,so I can uniquely identify user from app_remove automated event

Answer (score 0):

You can [set a user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties) which gets attached to all events logged by Google Analytics for Firebase.  These user properties will only be visible in [data exports to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7030014?hl=en).

Comment: Let me add and check if this is getting captured

Comment: Thanks Doug ! If I user Login User id as User property, so if two different users login on my device will my user property will be overridden by last active user on that device